# passing pointer to interface return type

Tags: go

```
type Person interface {
    getName() string
}

type person1 struct {
    name string
}

func (p person1) getName() string {
    return p.name
}

func testing(name string) Person {
    return &person1{
        name: name,
    }
}

func main() {
    // Call the getName method to print the name
    fmt.Println(testing("Rambo").getName())
}
```

My doubt is that testing function returns a Person interface but we can return pointer to Person interface (&person1) to it.Why is it so?

Comment: Look, this reads not like Go code at all. Stop this Person/Animal traditional OOP stuff, you simply cannot get this to work. Work through the Tour of Go once more to get a feeling fro the language. E.g. the method would be called `Name() string` and the interface `interface Namer {...}` as its only action is Name. No "get". Then: do not name stuff testing as this looks like `package testing`. To your actual question: You never use pointer-to-interface. Actually you don't. Read about how Methods sets in the spec and the Tour.

Answer (score 1):

In GoLang it can help to think of an interface as a contract rather than a type.  That is, anywhere you use an `interface` type, what you are actually saying is "any type that *satisfies this contract*".

In this case, you have defined a `Person` interface; as a contract, this will be satisfied by any type which implements all of the methods of that interface (irrespective of whether it implements any other methods), in this case a single `getName() string` method.

The `person1` type implements just such a function with a `person1` receiver.

Thanks to the automatic dereferencing of pointers, both a `person1` and a `*person1` satisfy the `Person` contract and so either may be legally used where a `Person` interface is expected/required.

### Additional Info

Because the `getName` method has a pointer receiver both pointers and values satisfy the `Person` contract in this case.  If the method had a `*person1` receiver then *only* pointer values would satisfy the `Person` contract.  It doesn't make any difference in your code because the testing function returns a pointer, but it *would* make a difference if `testing()` was returning a `person1{}` rather than a `&person1{}`.

You don't even have to manifest the contract as a formal type.  i.e. this code is exactly equivalent to your posted example:

```golang
type person1 struct {
    name string
}

func (p person1) getName() string {
    return p.name
}

func testing(name string) interface{ getName() string } {
    return &person1{
        name: name,
    }
}

func main() {
    // Call the getName method to print the name
    fmt.Println(testing("Rambo").getName())
}
```